# R - How do I pass a function as an argument to another function?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have a function I'm creating like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_function <- function(data, x, y){
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format())
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), as.Date("2019/01/05"),"1 day"), 
                 value = seq(.1,.5, .1))

df  

date        value      
2019-01-01    0.1         
2019-01-02    0.2         
2019-01-03    0.3         
2019-01-04    0.4 
2019-01-05    0.5

plot_function(df, x = "date", "value")
```

[image]

But what if I wanted to allow the user to be able to change the y axis to a percentage. How can I let them replace `scales::comma_format()`? This doesn't work:

```
plot_function <- function(data, x, y, y_format){

  ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = y_format)
}

plot_function(df, x = "date", "value", y_format = "scales::percent_format()")
```

I get this error:

```
"Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths"
```

Comment: What happens when you pass the function itself by removing the quotes?

Comment: Your solution would have worked if you just left the quotes off. `plot_function(df, x = "date", "value", y_format = scales::percent_format())`. It's important to note that `scales::percent_format()` itself is calling a function that returns a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
plot_function <- function(data, x, y, y_format){

 ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + 
 geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = y_format())

}

plot_function(df, x = "date", "value", y_format = scales::percent_format)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to set up the function using the `...` argument, so that passing a `labels` argument to `scale_y_continuous` is optional:

```
plot_function <- function(data, x, y, ...) {

  ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_y_continuous(...)
}

# Pass nothing to scale_y_continuous
plot_function(mtcars, x = "cyl", y="hp")

# Add some big numbers to mtcars
mtcars$hp = 1e5 * mtcars$hp

# Pass a labels argument to scale_y_continuous to get comma formatted values
plot_function(mtcars, x = "cyl", y="hp", labels=scales::comma)
```